# AMPScript for DateTime

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the below AMPScript in my email -

```
%%=Datepart(%%Appoint_DateTime%%, "Y")=%%
```

The output that I am getting is below -

```
 %%=Datepart(2016-06-16T14:43:00.000Z, "Y")=%%
```

Appoint_DateTime is a date type profile attribute. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double-percents are not necessary inside of an AMPScript function.  Try this:

```
%%=Datepart(Appoint_DateTime, "Y")=%%
```

or better:

```
%%[
var @appoint
set @appoint = AttributeValue("Appoint_DateTime") /* must include quotes */
]%%
<!-- other HTML -->
%%=Datepart(@appoint, "Y")=%%
```